# What can I do against the blue progress circles?

Tags: rocket-league

Since the Dropshot update, when I play Rocket League with two local players (split screen),

- I can not see my inventory (100% of items affected)
- I do not see what items I win (drops) (100%)
- I can not trade (100%)
- I can hardly change my car in the garage (50%)

It works fine with a single player. Not problems at all then.

Of course I don't trade with my splitscreen player, because he has exactly the same items as I (same account) but I trade with someone else. I am often playing locally with 2 PCs and 3 players (you can see that from the screenshot: one PC is German, other is English). It happens on both machines, depending on which one has the splitscreen. This pretty much excludes a hard disk problem.

If it happens, here's what it looks like until I restart Rocket League.

Screenshot of inventory:

[image: Rocket League Inventory]

Screenshot during trade:

[image: Rocket League Trade]

Screenshot during customizing:

[image: Rocket League Customizing]

Screenshot of drop after trade:

[image: Rocket League drop after trade]

I have already tried:

- check the integrity of local files via Steam
- look at [this Steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/154643795212364470/) and [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/3/350543389014995475/)
- look at [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/53rac9/dropsinventory_not_loading/)
- found this [RL Support Request](http://psyonix.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=27678&p=298115)

but none of them is really helpful.

What can I do against the blue progress circles?

Answer (score -3):

You may have faulty rocket league. Try: Steam>Library>Rocket league>Properties>Local data>Verify integrity of game cache.

Comment: Of course I don't trade with my splitscreen player, because he has exactly the same items as I. I am playing locally with 2 PCs and 3 players. It happens on both machines, depending on which one has the splitscreen. This pretty much excludes a hard disk problem.